# changing the color of links in a div on hover

Tags: html, href

I have a div that has a couple links in it and I was wondering if there was a way to change the global color of links when you hover over the div? Not that the color of the link changes when you hover over the link, but that all the links change color from the global link color when you hover over the div.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper CSS would be something like this

```
#divId:hover a:link,
#divId:hover a:visited,
#divId:hover a:active{color:#f00}
```

or

```
.divClass:hover a:link,
.divClass:hover a:visited,
.divClass:hover a:active{color:#f00}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
div:hover a {
   color: green;
}
```

should do the trick.